# Activator create generic instance

Tags: c#, generics

I noticed a strange behaviour with generic classes using a list of interfaces as a constructor parameter.

Let's say we have the following class

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : IInterface
{
    public GenericClass(int inInt, List<T> inList){
    }

    public GenericClass(int inInt, object inObject){
    }
}
```

When I try to create an instance like this (tmpType implements `IInterface`):

```
IEnumerable<IInterface> tmpSomeObjects = xy;

Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(tmpType), 5, (List<IInterface>)tmpSomeObjects);
```

The second constructor will be called (int, object).

I probably miss an important point... I expected the first constructor to be executed.

Comment: What is `ChangeTable<>` ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen updated my post, copy/paste error.

Comment: And **why** did you expect the first constructor be called? It explicitly asks for a `List<T>`, and we don't know the actual type of `xy` or `tmpSomeObjects` (other than what you've declared the variable as).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IEnumerable` is of type `IEnumerable<IInterface>`, but the type you are constructing has a generic parameter of a derived type, so it does not match the exact constructor.

Say `T` is `Foo` (which implements `IInterface`), your type becomes:

```
public class GenericClass<Foo>
{
    public GenericClass(int inInt, List<Foo> inList){
    }

    public GenericClass(int inInt, object inObject){
    }
}
```

Yet you are passing an `IEnumerable<IInterface>` (or `List<IInterface>`) to it, which doesn't match `List<Foo>`, so that's why it's preferring `object` (not only it's preferred... the other constructor won't match at all).

Try it: remove the constructor with `object` and try to do this:

```
var list = new List<IInterface>();
var x = new GenericClass<TypeImplementingIInterface>(5, list);
```

That won't even compile.

So the solution in your case would be simple... make the parameter in the constructor `IEnumerable<IInterface>`, instead of `List<T>`, which is what you actually want to pass it

Comment: I mixed up runtime and compile time. Thanks for the clarification! Indeed your answer would solve the problem, but on the other hand in case of a change to 'T : IInterface', I'd have to change the constructor parameter as well. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do this:

```
var list = new List<IInterface>();
new GenericClass<TmpType>(5, list);
```

However, `List<IInterface>` is not convertible to `List<TmpType>`, even though `TmpType` implements `IInterface`, so overload with object is chosen.

If you try with:

```
var list = new List<TmpType>();
// should work with Activator.CreateInstance too
new GenericClass<TmpType>(5, list);
```

Then it should choose first one.

Note that with `Activator.CreateInstance`, unlike "manual" invocation, runtime type of `list` does matter. So for example, this:

```
IEnumerable<IInterface> list = new List<TmpType>();   
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericType<>)).MakeGenericType(typeof(TmpType)), 5, list);
```

will choose first overload, because runtime-type is `List<TmpType>`. However this:

```
IEnumerable<IInterface> list = new List<TmpType>();
new GenericClass<TmpType>(1, list);
```

will chose second (with `object`), because now constructor is resolved at compile time.